# application-test.properties isn't loaded when activating profiles with <profiles>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use [new feature from Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html) -- activate profile via configuration of `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <profiles>
            <profile>test</profile>
        </profiles>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-application</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-application</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But in this case my integration test starts to fail, because of `IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.mail.host' in string value "${spring.mail.host}"`

This variable defined in `src/main/resources/application-test.properties`:

```
spring.profiles: test
spring.mail.host: 127.0.0.1
```

My test look like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(
    loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class,
    initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class,
    classes = TestContext.class
)
public class WhenAnonymousUserRegisterAccount extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    private String mailHost;
```

`TestContext` only defines `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` with another property files.

The interesting part is that if I remove `<profiles>` and activate profile from `application.properties` my test works:

```
spring.profiles.active: test
```

So, it looks like that when I'm using `<profiles>` Spring doesn't load `application-test.properties` file to the environment.

Questions:

- is it a bug?
- (if it's not) how to configure Spring to load `application-test.properties` and use `<profiles>`?
- why these approaches are differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the profiles in the configuration of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` then they are only available if you execute the application with that plugin, i.e. by running `mvn spring-boot:run`. I suspect, that's not the case for your integration test and thus it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` during the integration tests (I'm sorry, I removed that part to make question shorter, now I've added it).

Comment: How exactly do you run the integration tests? Also you should have a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-testng/src/test/java/sample/testng/SampleTestNGApplicationTests.java on which annotations you should use on the test (mainly the SpringApplicationConfiguration instead of ContextConfiguration).

Comment: I'm not sure that the cause in annotation that I used, because all work when I'm activating profile from `application.properties` file.

Comment: Yes, but the way you have configured your test, the test is initializing the application context and configuration. And usually the tests are called either by the maven surefire plugin or maven failsafe plugin, so the configuration for the spring-boot-maven-plugin doesn't apply for the test itself. Can you post the logfile of a maven build?

Comment: What dunni said. You can't expect your **test** to have the profile enabled. Only the app is. How about using `@ActiveProfiles("test")` on your test instead?

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll Ah, yes, that's it! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't fully understand what did you mean from the first time, but after example from @StéphaneNicoll I realized it.